# Where can I watch World Chess Championship 2021?

Tags: world-championship

What are the possible streams that I can watch World Chess Championship 2021 from 24th of November to 16th of December (any online platform and television broadcast)?

If possible, please provide information about who will be the casters and whether the stream will have the live feed of Carlsen and Nepo.

Comment: Should we add non-English streams too?

Comment: @walen Well I don't know. There is already an answer mentioning one. I think it is ok for some major ones.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Chess24 Global** is providing commentary with David Howell, Jovanka  Houska and Kaja Snare.

**Chess24 Deep Dive** is providing commentary with Anish Giri and Judit Polgar.

**Chess.com** is providing commentary with Robert Hess, Danny Rensch, Fabiano Caruana and Hou Yifan.

**FIDE** themselves are providing commentary on YouTube by Vishwanathan Anand and Anna Muzychuk.

And a number of other sources are also available for dedicated commentary via streaming (**Hikaru Nakamura**, **Ben Finegold**, **ChessBase India**, ...)

You're spoilt for choice really.

Comment: I think it says a lot about the popularity of chess that so many different sources are willing to commit to production quality coverage. Very happy to see this kind of thing.

Comment: NBC sports will also be broadcasting daily recaps/highlights with commentary by Maurice Ashley, not live but neat to see chess getting that sort of mainstream coverage too

Answer (score 5):

According to [this tweet from Chess24.com](https://twitter.com/chess24com/status/1460246216042680328) they will be broadcasting the event:

> We all know @DavidHowellGM from his ace commentary of the Meltwater
> @ChampChessTour. Now the three-time British champ (and former junior rival of Carlsen and Nepomniachtchi) is back to guide us through the FIDE World Championship on the #c24Global broadcast.
> [image]

Answer (score 4):

You can watch it on Chess.com. you can follow the live moves with computer analysis, live chat, and video commentary by grandmasters and special guests. I think Viswanathan Anand will be one of the official commentators and Caruana will also be joining in this commentators team.

Answer (score 4):

If we're accepting non-English mentions, the Norwegian Broadcasting Corporation (NRK) will be [following the games live](https://tv.nrk.no/serie/sjakk/2021/MSPO50650121), presumably with commentary by IM Torstein Bae with others, in Norwegian. That link currently claims it will be available worldwide (I don't think it was in 2018).

Historically their coverage has been aimed at a more casual audience (I expect them to explain things like en pessant and the restrictions on castling at least once during the games, along with relevant fundamental endgame theory like K vs K+B being a forced draw), and they have a funny fascination with the Stockfish evaluation ("pila", the arrow). But as a somewhat casual player myself, I have found it enjoyable in the past.